# Converting one Timezone to another

Tags: ruby, datetime, timezone

I'm working with Ruby. I want to convert UTC to various time conversion. I follow the link [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Time/Converttimetotimezone.htm).

My code is:

```
class TimeFormat
  def convert_zone(to_zone)
    original_zone = ENV["TZ"]
    utc_time = dup.gmtime
    ENV["TZ"] = to_zone
    to_zone_time = utc_time.localtime
    ENV["TZ"] = original_zone
    return to_zone_time
  end
end

t = TimeFormat.new
t.convert_zone("US/Pacific")
```

But it shows:

```
undefined method `gmtime' for #<TimeFormat:0x9043388> (NoMethodError)
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get an error when calling 'convert_zone' saying "undefined method `gmtime'", you are probably passing something instead of the required Time object as a parameter.

Here is something similar that you might looking for.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Time/Converttimetotimezone.htm

You can extend Time class and define your own method.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the class name as Time.

Then call it as,

```
t = Time.new
t.convert_zone("US/Pacific")
```

gmtime is a method of Time class.